# psql: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "root", database "root", SSL off

Tags: linux, postgresql

on our Linux server we have  PostgreSQL DB

when we type -

```
psql -l
```

we get

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "root", database "postgres", SSL off
```

what we need to set in the /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf in order to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To list the databases, you can execute your command as `postgres` user:

```
$ sudo su postgres -c 'psql -l'
```

If you are already logged in as root, you can remove `sudo` from the above command. User `postgres` is considered as root user for PostgreSQL database engine.

The error shown in your post indicates that there is no access for user `root` from `localhost` to access `postgres` database. So, you can edit `pg_hba.conf` file to include the desired login details like login name, DB name, and host. The file is well documented.

For your case, you can add the following line to `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
local   all       root           peer
```

You need to reload your postgresql server after saving the changes.

Comment: can you please advice how to edit the file pg_hba.conf  to solve this?

Comment: @jango: Updated my answer to allow access for root user.